# How to update global state from a list element?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm building a movie tracking app and I want to change movie's watch status from the movie's detail page. There is a list of movies. On press to an element, I'm passing movie object to detail view and trying to change watch status in there.

MovieListView.swift file:

```
struct MovieListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var movies: Movies

    var body: some View {
        List(movies.allMovies, id: \.title) { movie in
           NavigationLink(
            destination: MovieView(movie: movie)) {
            MovieItem(movie: movie)
           }
        }.navigationTitle("Movie List")
    }
}
```

MovieItem is a list item component and MovieView is a movie's detail screen.

MovieView.swift file

```
struct MovieView: View {

    let movie: Movie
        
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text(movie.title)            
            Text(movie.summary)

            Toggle("Watched", isOn: $movie.watched)            

        }
    }
}
```

In this example `isOn: $movie.watched` gives this error: `Cannot find '$movie' in scope`

I tried binding but since movie object that I pass to MovieView isn't a state, binding didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide a `@Binding`. With a list of items, that means you'll need some way to generate that `@Binding` so that the child view can update the original list. You can see that in the following code in the `bindingForId` function.

```
class Movies : ObservableObject {
    @Published var allMovies : [Movie] = [Movie(watched: false, title: "Movie 1", summary: "Summary 1"),Movie(watched: false, title: "Movie 2", summary: "Summary 2")]
    
    func bindingForId(id: UUID) -> Binding<Movie> {
        .init { () -> Movie in
            self.allMovies.first(where: { $0.id == id }) ?? Movie(watched: false, title: "", summary: "")
        } set: { (newValue) in
            self.allMovies = self.allMovies.map { movie in
                if movie.id == newValue.id { return newValue }
                return movie
            }
        }

    }
}

struct Movie {
    var id = UUID()
    var watched: Bool
    var title: String
    var summary : String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var movies: Movies = Movies()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(movies.allMovies, id: \.id) { movie in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: MovieView(movie: movies.bindingForId(id: movie.id))) {
                    Text(movie.title)
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Movie List")
        }
    }
}

struct MovieView: View {
    
    @Binding var movie: Movie
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(movie.title)
            Text(movie.summary)
            Toggle("Watched", isOn: $movie.watched)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I changed your `ForEach` to use `id` -- using the `title` could get funny if you have two movies that share a title. If you didn't want to use an ID, you'd have to modify that `bindingForId` function to filter based on a title.

I also included enough boilerplate code to get it running as an example for me (adding a `NavigationView`, using `@ObservedObject`, adding sample data, etc), but none of that should have a bearing on the approach to the original question. One important thing, though, is to note that `Movie` is a `struct`.

Comment: Isn`t better using index? instead of looking for single item and searching it each time?

Comment: Not really -- `index` is very fragile. For example, what if the order changes? In an app with data that is synced from an online source, for example, that could change easily while on the detail view.

Comment: Even not in enumerated way?

Comment: `enumerated` just uses indexes. I'm not saying you can't do it -- I'm just saying it is inherently more fragile than using IDs.

Comment: I know what you mean, but Binding would use multiple time that **first** here and there, even for not real update, and I think it brings the system on knee in that way.

Comment: Perhaps in the case of thousands of elements or hugely complex data structures. Certainly not the case here, and it avoids very real and common problems with reordering, which would be potential issues with using index. Beware of premature optimization that can cause bugs in other areas.